# Why does eating cauliflower with spicy food help to take away the spciy burning feeling in your mouth?

Tags: cauliflower

Why does eating cauliflower with spicy food help to take away the spciy burning feeling in your mouth?

Comment: Are you sure it's the cauliflower? Where there other ingredients, especially fatty ones?